# redirecting http to https (only frontend not admin panel )

Tags: regex, .htaccess, ssl, opencart

I installed SSL for opencart but https only show up in ac login,checkout pages etc ( i know its a default behavior), i want to show it on all frontend pages (i know it may slow down website and its not necessary  but my client wants it on all pages ).
So i have tried this code in .htaccess file in root directory

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

this does the work but it forces mysite/admin to also https and for strange reasons, i can't login to my admin if this code is used.

what i am seeking is either there is some regex that will stop forcing https for pages starting with mysite/admin or better if someone opencart expert like jay gillford has solution for it by adding some lines in config.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to edit your `config.php` file and `admin/config.php` file. In these, change the `HTTP_SERVER` domain string from `http://` to `https://`. This should then use HTTPS globally. Also change the `HTTPS_SERVER` if you've not done so. You should do the same for the `HTTP_IMAGE` and `HTTPS_IMAGE` too

Comment: what a simple and elegant idea, i already set the HTTPS_server to https but setting HTTP_server also to https was great

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answers are the best :)